# Как поменять цвет текста на множестве кнопок

Tags: android, android-button, gridlayoutmanager

У меня есть большое количество кнопок в `gridlayout`, поменять фон легко, просто через цикл, но как поменять цвет текста для всех кнопок программно?

Comment: А фон Вы програмно меняете?

Comment: Точно так же, как и фон, только метод другой: `button.setTextColor(Color.RED);`. Но куча кнопок прямо в разметке это не хорошее решение - советую рассмотреть возможность переписать на `RecyclerView` + `GridLayoutManager` или хотя бы старый `GridView`

Comment: А по какому принципу вы хотите менять цвет текста?

Comment: @Style-7 для всех кнопок поставить цвет напрмер белый

Comment: попробуйте через VIewGroup (в вашем случае GridLayout) в цикле выбрать через getChildAt( index ) и поменять цвет текста

Comment: @Style-7 там можно только фон поменять и некоторые другие свойства, но не цвет текста

Comment: setTextColor - работает

Answer (score 0):

Можно так же циклом поменять и цвет текста всех кнопок,

но я бы посоветовал вам создать свой класс расширяющий (наследующий класс кнопки) и добавил бы туда настройки цвета, после чего использовал свой созданный класс view в файле разметки, обращаться к нему можно через полное название класса

Comment: А я бы не советовал делать кастомный класс при том, что задавать цвета можно стандартному точно так же - хоть в разметке, хоть программно.